# tree hierarchy problem

Tags: php, data-structures, tree

i am in a situation where i need to the build the tree from the child nodes i.e i have to travese from child node to the parent my question is is it possible and what is the algorithm for this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you give an example of your data structure?

Comment: Building a tree from the bottom up doesn't necessarily require upwards traversal. Please explain what you are trying to achieve in greater detail.

Comment: e.g i have maintain categories in my db with parent child relationship now in one of my scenario i need to show only categories along with parents for specific products i.e. i retreive only the categories specific to my desired products and from that categories i need to build the tree

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did something similar to what you're looking for. I think this should work for you, with minor adjustments. Excuse the Wordpressiness - you should be able to figure out what it's doing, anyways.

```
function find_parents( $category_id ) {

    global $wpdb;

    $category = $category_id;

    while (1) {

        $parent_category = $wpdb->get_row(
            $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM hierarchy WHERE id=%d", $category)
        );

        $data[] = array( id => $parent_category->id, name => $parent_category->category_name );

        if ($parent_category->parent_id == 0) {
            break;
        }

        $category = $parent_category->parent_id;

    }

    return $data;

}
```

This will return an array in reverse order an item or category, and each subsequent parent.

The function to go the opposite direction, from the top category down and will retrieve ALL categories, is:

```
function find_children( $parent_id, $data ) {

    foreach ( $data as $child ) {

        if ( $child->parent_id == $parent_id ) {
            $children[] = array(
                'attr' => array(
                    'id' => 'cat_' . $child->id,
                    'dbid' => $child->id,
                    'link_to' => $child->link_to,
                    'rel' => ( $child->link_to ? 'link' : 'default' )
                ),
                'data' => $child->category_name,
                'children' => find_children( $child->id, $data )
            );
        }

    }

    return $children;

}
```

Between the two of them, you'll probably be able to cobble something together, I hope :/

Comment: thanks for the answer in my case i have more than two categories and categories can have same parent or any category can also be itself parent any solution  ?

Comment: So you want to find sibling-level categories as well?

Comment: ok, I edited the original solution to have a related function, one that goes the other way and gathers the entire hierarchy together. This comes from a table with the format: id int (the category id number), category_name varchar, parent_id int (which category it belongs in, 0 if top-level), weight int (the order in which it displays) and link_to int (an internal pointer for my system). Hopefully this makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Using self-referencing relationships (or Adjacency List Model) to represent hierarchical data is never a good idea. The best way to do that is by using Interval Trees or Nested Sets. The best reference I've seen so far on the subject is the one on the MySQL Developer Zone website which can be found [here](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/). I've actually used this article (and other resources) to write my own implementation in C# using Lambda Expressions. But the article I referenced does a great job in explaining the concept and showing some ready-to-use SQL code.